# WSGI ( Python ) Connecting to MYSQL via SOCKET rather than via "localhost" or "127.0.0.1"

Tags: mysql, python-2.7, mod-wsgi, wsgi, iptables

Obtained information suggests MYSQL would be much faster 
if one connects to MYSQL via MYSQL SOCKET ..

This is my current wsgi script:

```
import _mysql

def b():
    a=_mysql.connect('127.0.0.1','user','','db',3306)
    return a

def application(environ, start_response):    
    start_response('200 OK', [('content-type', 'text/html')])
    yield "a"
```

in this above example.. to connect to mysql i am connecting it via 127.0.0.1 and thus i must also use a PORT.

the problem here.. is..

there is too much TCP OVERHEAD given that in iptables i have to open port 3306 and so on..

such as grant access to 127.0.0.1

the question is.. how to use MYSQL SOCKET so that everything can be "MORE DİRECT" and thus never any transactions with iptables. TCP etc..

**UPDATE**

```
[root@a ~]# mysql_config --socket
/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
```

Comment: I thought the _mysql lib utelized unix sockets automaticly if possible? as long as you're using `localhost` as the hostname. http://mysql-python.sourceforge.net/MySQLdb.html#some-mysql-examples problem is you're still going to get overhead with unix sockets.. just a different kind of issues.

Comment: i want to use "/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock" instead of "localhost" .. i want to go beyond "localhost".

Comment: As i sad, I think the lib does that for you when you say "localhost". I can be wrong, but i think it does.. and the docs give a hint about it too.